# Python3 - use function parameter as name of variable

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a function that creates different forms of arrays and I don't know how to differentiate them. Is something similar to this possible?

```
def array_creator(nameArray):
    nameArray = [0,1,2]

array_creator(a)
print(a)  # prints [0,1,2]
```

At the moment I always run the function and then assign manually variables to store the arrays.
Thanks!

Comment: but why not just do `a = [0, 1, 2]`? Why confuse people by assigning to the global scope from inside a function?

Comment: Why not just return the array, instead of using an "output-parameter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you do this by returning a value from the function and binding this value to a local name, ie:

```
def array_creator():
    return [0, 1, 2]

a = array_creator()
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example to work you need to define your variable `a` before you use it. E.g. `a = []`. However your example won't work the way you want to. The reason for this is that you assign a new object (`[1, 2, 3]`) to your `nameArray` variable in line 2. This way you lose the reference to your object `a`. However it is possible to change your object `a` from inside the function.

```
def array_creator(nameArray):
    nameArray.extend([0,1,2])

a = []
array_creator(a)
print(a)  # prints [0,1,2]
```

This will work. Have a look at [How to write functions with output parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have "output parameters", hence a plain assignment will only change the *binding* of the local variable, but will not modify any value, nor change bindings of variables outside the function.

However `list`s are mutable, so if you want to modify the argument just do so:

```
nameArray[:] = [0,1,2]
```

This will replace the contents of `nameArray` with `0,1,2` (works if `nameArray` is a `list`).

An alternative is to have your function simply return the value you want to assign:

```
def array_creator():
    values = [0, 1, 2]
    return values

my_arr = array_creator()
```

Finally, if the function wants to modify a `global`/`nonlocal` variable you have to declare it as such:

```
a = [1,2,3]

def array_creator():
    global a
    a = [0,1,2]

print(a)   # [1,2,3]
array_creator()
print(a)   # [0,1,2]
```

Or:

```
def wrapper():
    a = [1,2,3]
    def array_creator():
        nonlocal a
        a = [0,1,2]
    return a, array_creator

a, creator = wrapper()

print(a)   # [1,2,3]
creator()
print(a)   # [0,1,2]
```

Note however that it is generally **bad practice** to use global variables in this way, so try to avoid it.